# proving an Injective and surjective function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

i have a question about injective and surjective functions, i don't seem to understand it right i tried multiple sources including my books of course and i seem to get stuck mostly in the surjective proving questions.
my question is -
**f:N→N prove that f is injective if and only if for every 2 different and infinite sets A,B⊆N,f[A]≠f[B]**

i started from the side of proving that f is an injective , i did it by contradiction saying that f[A]=f[B] and if the function is an injective then A=B and for every element in the range there is only one element that gets in from the domain and since i stated that A=B it means there is more than one so it cant be right therefore  f[A]≠f[B] and they are not equal. **now i don't know if what i did is even right .. and i couldn't prove it the other way around (other side)**

and the second question is-
**f:N→N prove that f is surjective if and only if for every 2 different and infinite sets A,B⊆N,f^-1[A]≠f^-1[B]**
for this i had no clue how to even start..can someone help explain about surjective and injective functions please ?

thank you all for the big help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statements about injectivity are often easier to prove by contrapositive. So I'll prove

1. if there are two different infinite sets $A$ and $B$ such that $f[A]=f[B]$, then $f$ is not injective;
2. if $f$ is not injective, then there are two different infinite sets $A$ and $B$ such that $f[A]=f[B]$.

Suppose there exists two different infinite sets $A$ and $B$ such that $f[A]=f[B]$. Then, without loss of generality, we can assume there is $a\in A$ such that $a\notin B$. From $f[A]=f[B]$, we conclude there is $b\in B$ with $f(b)=f(a)$. Since $b\ne a$, we conclude that $f$ is not injective.

Now let's tackle the converse. Suppose $f$ not injective. Then there are $a$ and $b$ with $a\ne b$ and $f(a)=f(b)$. Take $C=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{a,b\}$. This is infinite and so are $A=C\cup\{a\}$ and $B=C\cup\{b\}$. Conclude.

For surjectivity, you might want to use the fact that $f$ is surjective if and only if, for every $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, $f[f^{-1}[A]]=A$.