# Prove that function is injective if images are not equal

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let's say I have a function $ f: \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N} $

I also have the given infinite nonempty sets that $(A,B\subseteq\mathbb{N})\land(A \cap B=∅)$. Some element $a$ belongs to $A$ and some element $b$ belongs to $B$.

We must prove that

> $f$ is injective $ \iff f[A]≠f[B]$

My attempt was to prove by contradiction that the following statements are impossible:

I. $f[A]=f[B]$

II. $f$ is not injective

---

If I. is true, then there is an $a$ in $A$ that could be equal to $b$ in $B$. It's a contradiction, because we know that $A$ and $B$ are totally different.

Now I'm a bit confused about II. One can say that if $f$ is not injective, then $f(a)=f(b)\implies a=b$, a contradiction because the sets are different. But is it a correct way? I based it on intuition only because I can't find any useful lemmas.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$? Fixed set or arbitrary set?

Comment: They are infinite sets

Comment: You did not answer my question.

Comment: It is only stated that these sets are completely different and infinite. I think they are arbitrary sets.

Comment: Don’t use “groups” to mean “sets”. “Groups” has a technical meaning.

Comment: Arturo, you are right!

Answer (score 1):

I´m not exactly sure if you stated the problem correctly, but I´m guessing the theorem goes as follows:

Given a function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, then $f$ is injective if and only if for any two non-empty disjoint subsets $A,B$ of $\mathbb{N}$ (that is $A \cap B =\varnothing$), $f[A]\neq f[B]$.

Now, by trying to prove it by arriving to a contradiction, you must say which implication you are trying to prove (remember there are two implications involved in this kind of theorems).

Also, you should be quite confident on knowing the definitions involved in the theorem, and you should try, step by step to find the logical negation of what you are supposed to prove. I say this because when you mention I. and II., that is not going to get you to arrive to any contradiction, because, taking the contrapositive of $f$ is injective $\Rightarrow f[A] \neq f[B]$, you get $f[A]=f[B] \Rightarrow $ $f$ is not injective, so it is possible (and it will happen) that both I. and II..

Now then, your intuiton is kind of correct. Let's try to prove, by contradiction that if $f$ is injective, then any two disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ have different images. Let´s suppose that the latter isn't true. Then, there exists a pair of non-empty subsets, $A$ and $B$, such that $A\cap B = \varnothing$, but $f[A]=f[B]$. Let $a\in A$. Then, $f(a)\in f[A]$, but $f[A]=f[B]$, therefore, $f(a)\in f[B]$. But what does it mean that $f(a)\in f[B]$? Well, it means that there exists an element $b\in B$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$, and this is where you use the hypothesis that $f$ is injective. Because $f(a)=f(b)$, it happens that $a=b$, which means $a\in A\cap B$, and there is the contradiction, which is basically what you said, just a little more developed.

For the other implication, trying to arrive to a contradiction also works, so check it by yourself. The correct way of stating it is to suppose that $f$ is a function that satisfies that for any two non-empty disjoint subsets $A,B$ of $\mathbb{N}$ , $f[A]\neq f[B]$, and however, it is not injective (be sure to check what it would mean for $f$ not to be injective).

Hope this helps!

(Also, note that this does not require any information about the natural numbers nor anything related to infinite sets)

Comment: I think you are missing “nonempty” in describing the sets. Otherwise, you can take $A=B=\varnothing$, and even if $f$ is injective and even though $A\cap B=\varnothing$, you still get $f[A]=f[B]$.

Comment: That's right! Let me fix it.

Comment: So I found what I think is the original problem that you're trying to solve, and it is not what my guess was. Here's the link, it's already solved, but be sure to try it yourself before, just check  the statement of the theorem.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3622423/proving-an-injective-and-surjective-function?rq=1

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've read it carefully now.